# Why the progressBar green color never reach 100%?

Tags: c#, winforms

The progressBarEx1 value is 100% after each file download completed. But the green color inside is not reaching to the end.

I want that when a file downloaded completed the green color will smooth reach to the end to 100% before starting over to the next time.

The green color does reach 100% to the end only when all the files have been downloaded.

```cs
client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    lblStatus.Text = $"Status: Download of file {i + 1}/{totalFiles} completed.";
    progressBarEx1.Value = 100;
};
```

I tried to set the Value to 100 when a file download is complete but it's not changing much.

[image: 100%]

I used `Thread.Sleep` just to display the green color:

[image: the percentages sometimes show 99% sometimes 100% and also the green color never reaching to the end]

Sometimes the percentages in the label inside the progressBar show 99% sometimes a bit less sometimes 100% but the green color is never reaching to the end.

And if I'm using a breakpoint I see that when a file download completes the value of the progressBar is 100% but not showing 100%.

and it's downloading the files fine the files are on the hard disk.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Download_Files
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> links = new List<string>
{
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
    // Add more URLs as needed
};

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async Task DownloadAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                int totalFiles = links.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++)
                {
                    var currentFile = links[i];
                    var destinationPath = $@"d:\testfiles\100MB{i}.bin";

                    client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        lblStatus.Text = $"Status: Download of file {i + 1}/{totalFiles} completed.";
                        progressBarEx1.Value = 100;
                    };

                    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => progressBarEx1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => lblDownloadInfo.Text = "Download Info: " + FormatBytes(e.BytesReceived);
                    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        
                    };

                    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(currentFile), destinationPath);
                }
            }
        }

        private async void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DownloadAsync();
        }

        public static string FormatBytes(long bytes)
        {
            const int scale = 1024;
            string[] units = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };

            int magnitude = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(bytes, scale));

            double adjustedSize = bytes / Math.Pow(scale, magnitude);
            string format = (magnitude > 0 && magnitude < 3) ? "F2" : "F0"; // Show two decimal places for KB and MB, no decimals for others

            return $"{adjustedSize.ToString(format)} {units[magnitude]}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of `Thread.Sleep` there? in fact, with that action you freeze the rendering of the UI, and that's likely because you don't see the very end part of the progress bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result from breaking your `DownloadAsync` function into two part.

One to run iteration to get/download each file and another to download file and update the progress bar.

```cs
private async Task DownloadAsync()
{
    int totalFiles = links.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++)
    {
        var currentFile = links[i];
        await DownloadFile(currentFile, i, totalFiles);
        await Task.Delay(10000); //set your desired delay period
    }
}
public async Task DownloadFile(string currentFile, int i, int totalFiles)
{

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var destinationPath = $@"d:\testfiles\100MB{i}.bin";

        client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            lblStatus.Text = $"Status: Download of file {i + 1}/{totalFiles} completed.";
            progressBarEx1.Value = 100;
        };

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => progressBarEx1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => lblDownloadInfo.Text = "Download Info: " + FormatBytes(e.BytesReceived);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
        {

        };

        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(currentFile), destinationPath);
    }
}
```

**Note: I have added `Task.Delay(10000)` in `DownloadAsync` which will delay the download process to show `ProgessBar = 100` clearly.**

Comment: working.  and why when it start downloading a file i see the label lblDownloadInfo.Text = "Download Info: " + FormatBytes(e.BytesReceived); get report progress i see the amount size getting up but the progressBar start updating only about 2 seconds later ?  like there is no sync between the progressChange the lblDownloadInfo get update and the progressBar is only 2-3 seconds later.

Comment: progressBar shows only interger percentage like 1%,2% not 0.5% or 0.75%. That mentioned delay depand upon your file size and internet speed.